# Ajax error function in cordova Framework7

Tags: ios, cordova, request, html-framework-7

**Problem:** using the app.request function in framework7. in Android, it works fine but in iOS, it throws this below error and not executing code in error function.

```
2018-03-27 18:13:23.635876+0530 Appname[2624:104055] CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds.  Error=-25300, query={
    class = inet;
    "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
    ptcl = htps;
    "r_Attributes" = 1;
    sdmn = "apps.sample.co.in";
    srvr = "apps.sample.co.in";
    sync = syna;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

using https://github.com/silkimen/cordova-plugin-advanced-http plugin to make http call only for iOS solves the issue.
reference: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-call-rest-service-no-catch-http-response-code-401-on-ios/107690/1